# How is the input of 7905 determined?

Tags: voltage-regulator, 7805

I have read that the max input voltage for this IC is -7V and max output voltage is -15.6V. According to it's name, the output voltage should be max -5V.

[I read this here.](http://www.dadaelectronics.eu/shop/components/ics/voltage-regulators/7905-voltage-regulator)

But for 7805 IC, the max output voltage is +5V and input voltage is max 35V.
I don't understand why is there so much difference in voltages for both the ICs.

Also, if the max voltage for 7905 is -7V, can we get output if we supply 0V to it?

Comment: FInd a real data sheet... eg. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm79.pdf

Comment: Yes, I read the datasheet, and I was to order the IC in bulk online. But the description mentioned in the website confused me and made me ask here before ordering it.

Comment: As an aside, when buying components, always buy from a reputable distributor, otherwise who knows what you'll get. This is especially true when buying in bulk.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I will keep this in mind from now. Thanks :) Actually I used this because I had coupons to get discounts from this website. Haha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page seems to be messing up numbers from the different LM79XX parts.

You need to look at a proper [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm79.pdf).

[image]

[image]

It looks like they mistakenly copied the other number from the 7915 version.

[image]

And no.. if you have zero volts in you will get zero volts out.

Comment: Thanks alot!!! This cleared my confusion of input and output voltage for 79XX.

Answer (score 0):

"max output voltage is -15.6V" is obviously incorrect.
I will here assume it is the minimum input voltage.

Max -7V and min -16.5V because they are **negative numbers**.  0V is higher than the maximum of -7.  Going below the minimum input voltage would exceed the absolute maximum ratings.

The site you found it on is indeed confusing and they are combining two ways to think of negative voltages.  It's a complete mess and you should read the real datasheet instead.

Comment: Nah.. they just read the max from the 7915 column

Comment: So I think, there's nothing to worry about for ordering it online from that website, right?